# controlling the button enable property in C# with if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, button, properties

I've been trying make an if statement which will enable the button, but I'm not sure where I made the mistake.

```
private void btnPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double MonthlyPayment = 0;
        double interest = cboInterest.SelectedIndex;
        double term = cboTerm.SelectedIndex;
        double principal = Double.Parse(txtPrincipal.Text);
        double expN = Math.Pow(1+interest, term*12)-1;

        MonthlyPayment = principal * (((interest / 12) * expN) / (expN - 1));

        string strMP = MonthlyPayment.ToString();
        string intrst = interest.ToString();
        string trm = term.ToString();
        string princ = principal.ToString();

        if (principal >= 0)
        {
            this.btnPayment.Enabled = true;
        }
        lblResult.Text = "The monthly payment for a loan of $" + princ + " at " + intrst + "% for " + trm + " years is $" + strMP; 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you can do this `this.btnPayment.Enabled = principal >= 0;`, and make the button `Enabeled= false;` on page load event. Make sure in your aspx file, there is no enabled attribute in the button.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and seeing what 'principal' is when it hits the if statement? Also, is the btnPayment supposed to be firing the btnPayment_Click event?

Comment: I tried "this.btnPayment.Enabled = principal >= 0;" for made sure the button Enabled = false. Nothing seemed to change I'm using visual studio and I'm pretty new to C# and visual studio. when you said to make sure the button Enabled=false, I'm guessing you mean to do that in the properties menu.

Comment: - sr28, I'm actually not sure how to see results of what specific lines of code do when they are compiled at runtime except by looking at the output window. I just know that they aren't any errors popping up yet when I run everything.

Answer (score 0):

This is never going to work, you're trying to enable the button from the click event of a button you have disabled? Atleast that is what i can see.

I think you need to put a check on txtPrincipal.Text leave event. i.e when a user leaves this text box, there should be function that checks whether a value is present and is greater than 0. If these conditions are met than your button should be enabled.

Comment: I clearly have a lot more studying to do because I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: All you need to do for now is: remove this code:  if (principal >= 0)
        {
            this.btnPayment.Enabled = true;
        } from here

Comment: and put the same code in the leave event of txtPrincipal textbox